# Значение слова ШИВОРОТ-НАВЫВОРОТ

Tags: этимология

Значение и происхождение слова **шиворот-навыворот**.

Comment: @serg_averch, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Значение: наоборот, наизнанку, противоположно тому, как следует. Происхождение: «Шиворотом» в Московской Руси именовался расшитый воротник боярской одежды, один из знаков достоинства вельможи. В дни Ивана Грозного подвергшегося царскому гневу и опале боярина нередко сажали на тощую клячу спиной вперед, надев на него одежду тоже наизнанку, шиворот-навыворот, то есть наоборот. В таком виде опального возили по всему городу, под свист и улюлюканье уличной толпы.